# Meteor mobile-config.js accessRule not working

Tags: ios, meteor, ios-simulator

I am getting a whitelist error when running my app on the iOS simulator. This is my mobile-config.js file which is located in client/js/mobile-config.js

```
App.info({
  id: 'com.example.matt.uber',
  name: 'über',
  description: 'Get über power in one button click',
  author: 'Matt Development Group',
  email: 'contact@example.com',
  website: 'http://example.com'
});

// Set up resources such as icons and launch screens.
App.icons({
  'iphone': 'icons/icon-60.png',
  'iphone_2x': 'icons/icon-60@2x.png',
  // ... more screen sizes and platforms ...
});

App.launchScreens({
  'iphone': 'splash/Default~iphone.png',
  'iphone_2x': 'splash/Default@2x~iphone.png',
  // ... more screen sizes and platforms ...
});

App.accessRule('*');
```

But the access rule doesn't update cordova's automatically generated config.xml file with the new accessRule.

UPDATE:

I moved the config-mobile.js to the root directory of my meteor project. Now the config.xml is being updated with the "*" access rule. BUT I still get a whitelist rejection error in the simulator. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding access rules only as needed:

```
App.accessRule('https://*.cloudfront.net/*');
App.accessRule('https://pbs.twimg.com/*');
```

Also prefer using of https over http.